# How to reference, Shared mailbox hosted on Exchange Server

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm attempting to reference a shared inbox in `Outlook` hosted on our exchange server. The method I've found

```
outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").getSharedDefaultFolder(inbox_owner, folder_type)
```

only returns a users main inbox (at least, when I tried using myself as the inbox_owner, my main inbox was returned.

how can I retrieve a shared inbox? the root folder is named inbox for both the personal and the shared inbox that I'm trying to reference so selecting by name is not an option.